# longevity of iPad Smart Cover

Tags: ipad

Since the launch of the iPad 2 I have been using a cover that I painted so I am reluctant to replace it. However the inside surface of the cover seems to be thinning or just becoming generally less fuzzy and it is doing less to clean the screen. In particular it is leaving vertical stripes that don't get cleaned. What kind of time are people getting out of their covers and is there any way to rejuvenate them or is there any material thin enough and effective at cleaning that can be bonded to the inside of the cover?

This cover dates from iPad 2 launch - have these covers changed during their lifetime or are they still the same inside and out? I know they have not changed specifically for "new iPad" but I read one forum post that claimed the inside material had changed.

[image: my iPad cover - Travis]

Looks to me like the leather covers might be less resilient - I saw one only about six months old that looked very shiny and polished inside, like worn suede.

Comment: For what it's worth, my brand new leather smart cover also leaves vertical strips of finger grease where the folds are located.

Comment: @bmike - same for my polyester cover.

Comment: Ditto for my leather one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The smart covers, generally do leave the vertical stripes. This happens when the fold areas of the cover do not touch the screen when it is closed. If you remove the smart cover fold it up and hold it horizontaly while wiping down the screen you will remove these stripes.

I have found that after owning 2 covers, both ployuretherene, that the microfiber lininng does start to fade away, but this like most things will be determined by the amount of use, and whether you take care of the cover.

Try not to let the microfiber part touch any dirty surfaces when it is off, or you are using it as a stand.

To clean the microfiber lining you are better to use another microfiber cloth.

They have changed since first release. My first one was a lighter green on the outside and grey on the inside, the covers now all have matching inside colours and slightly more contrast in the clolour of the outside